# Access SYSVOL share from non domain joined system (using C#)

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I'm searching for the best way to achieve the following with the least security impact:
A non domain joined system should be able to access \\$Domain\SYSVOL without joining the domain (Starting from Windows Server 2008 R2).
What would be the best way to achieve this? I've tried to direct access SYSVOL via the Explorer with credentials from a user in the given AD, but always got an exception that I've not sufficient permissions to access the directory. It always only seems to be possible on a domain joined system, which sadly is no viable option.

(In the long term I want to be able to crawl through multiple SYSVOL-directories of different ADs via a C# application.)

Disclaimer: I'm more of a Linux guy trying to fiddle my way through Windows/AD =). I've crawled through the web a lot now but can't really find a way to make some progress.

Cheers,
Finn

Answer (score 0):

Just to leave it here in case someone stumbles upon this: I had to do the login via the DC-URI like dc1.my-awesome-forest.com and everything went smooth after that.